# Pointwise a.e convergence implies boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of real valued functions with
$$f_n(t) \to f(t)$$
pointwise almost every $t.$ Does it follow that $|f_n(t)| < K$ for some constant $K$? I only know this fact for pointwise convergence.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Also, what do you mean by "I know this fact for pointwise convergence"?

Comment: I meant if $f_n$ converged to $f$ pointwise everywhere then $f_n$ are bounded.

Comment: Is it not even bounded a.e.?

Comment: What are you talking about?  Pointwise convergence doesn't imply boundedness.  If f_n(t) = t for all n, then f_n(t) converges to t, but f_n isn't bounded.

Comment: Isn't there a result that every convergent sequence is bounded????

Comment: The result you refer to says that if a sequence $(a_n)$ of real number converges to a *real number* $a$ then the sequence must be bounded (for any $\varepsilon$ all but finitely many $a_n$ is $\varepsilon$ away from the limit point $a$...).

Comment: The result that every convergent sequence is bounded is about convergent sequences in a metric space.  But pointwise convergence of functions is not equivalent to convergence in any metric space.  Pointwise convergence of functions is equivalent to convergence in R^R with the product topology, but that's not a metric space (in fact it's not metrizable).

Comment: You are missing something (see first answer).  Are you assuming $f$ is bounded?

Comment: Thanks for all comments. @StefanSmith I misunderstood convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For extended measurable functions*

Just having a limit does not say anything about boundedness. In fact we may choose $f_n(x)=n$ which converges to $f(x)=+\infty$.

However, if we know $|f_n(x)|<K$ for all $n$ and almost all $x$, then $|f(x)|\leq K$ for almost all $x$ (to see this use that a countable union of sets of measure zero has measure zero).

Also, if we knew $|f(x)|\leq K$ for almost all $x$, then $f_n(x)=f(x) + \infty\chi_{(n,+\infty)}(x)$ converges pointwise to $f$ - so that does not help either.

*For finite measurable functions*

Consider the function  $f(x)= \frac1x$, which is unbounded at $x=0$. Define $f_n(x)=f(x)$when $|x|>1/n$ and $f_n(x)=0$ otherwise. Then $f_n\to f$ a.e. but $f_n$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

What if $f_n(x)=x$ whenever $x$ is an integer multiple of n, and 0 otherwise ? This seems to contradict the result even for pointwise convergence though...

Answer (score 1):

> Consider $f_n(t)=\frac{1}{n}$ if $|t|\le \frac{1}{n}$ and $|t|$ if $|t|>\frac{1}{n}$, Then $\langle f_n(t)\rangle$ converges pointwise to $f(t)=|t|$ but each $f_n$ is unbounded!

Comment: Even simpler, just let $f_n(t) = |t|$!  The OP is missing something.